# Is there a way that POWERBI does not agregate all numeric data?

Tags: powerbi, xlsx

Powerbi aggregates all numeric data (using: count, sum, etc.) In their community they suggest to create new measures, the thing is, in that case I HAVE TO CREATE A LOT OF MEASURES...Also, I tried to convert the data to text and even so, Powerbi counts it!!!

any help, pls?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to tackle this:

- When you pull a field into the field well for a visualisation, you can click the drop down in the field well and select "Don't summarize"
- in the data model, select the column and on the ribbon select "don't summarize" as the summarization option in the Properties group.

The screenshot shows the field well option on the left and the data model options on the right, one for a numeric and one for a text field.

[image]

And, yes, you never want to use the implicit measures, i.e. the automatic calculations that Power BI creates. If you want to keep on top of what is being calculated, create your own measures, and yes, there will be many.

**Edit:** If by "aggregating" you are referring to the fact that text values will be grouped in a table (you don't see any duplicates), then you need to add a column with unique values to the table so all the duplicates of the text values show up. This can be done in the data source by adding an Index column, then using that Index column in the table and setting it to a very narrow with to make it invisible.

Comment: hey! @teylyn many thanks for reaching out :) I don't get the option "don't summarize" as ur painel in the left. Only the right one on: column tools.

Comment: Well, how about taking the guesswork out of the equation and post YOUR screenshot. Edit your question, then post a comment.

Comment: @GregGalloway I'd hope that someone who asks about Power BI would use Power BI and not Excel Power Pivot, but, hey, you never know.

Comment: Hey @teylyn thanks for all ur afford, I used a workaround on the data side, since powerbi was always aggregating info and i didn't want it.

Comment: I added a suggestion to my answer. See if that fits your problem. It would still have been better if you could have taken the trouble to describe your problem in more detail, given the fact that people are taking the time trying to help you and you force us to guess rather than give us all the info.

Answer (score 0):

The least tedious way I know of to turn off automatic summarization is as follows:

1. Open Model View
2. In the "Data" Pane, open the dropdowns for the tables of interest
3. Use CTRL-click to select multiple variables/column names. You can make selections in multiple tables.
4. In the "Properties" pane, scroll down to the bottom and open the "Advanced" dropdown
5. Set "Summarize by" to "None"